# Python how to correctly switch between defines, bools, functions?

Tags: python

I have a simple system over here and what I want to do here is to switch between TicketReg and while True method. Or is there any other way to do that? What I want to do is: In the TicketReg I have this function to break the whole loop, but that's not what I would like to do here. What I want to do here correctly is break the whole TicketReg and return again to While True and after that continue with TicketReg again.

```
elif 'n' in Reg_Time_Verification or 'N' in Reg_Time_Verification:
    break
```

The way this all works, when system see registered numbers exits the TicketReg function and return to while True to enter the car numbers again to continue.

```
def TicketReg(car_numb):
    while Registration:
        try:
            Reg_Time = int(input(' * Registration for: {}. Please pick a time (Minimum {})... '.format(car_numb, Min_Time)))
            if Reg_Time < Min_Time:
                print("* Minimum registration time is {} !".format(Min_Time))
            elif Reg_Time > Max_Time: 
                print("* Minimum registration time is {} h. !".format(Max_Time))
            elif Reg_Time >= Min_Time and Reg_Time <= Max_Time :
                Reg_Time_Verification = input('* Are you sure to register: {} for {} hours ? '.format(car_numb,Reg_Time))
                if 'y' in Reg_Time_Verification:
                    with open(Registrations, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as RegistrationC:
                        if 'Number: %s ' % (car_numb) in RegistrationC.read():
                            print("*Already existing vehicle!")
                            break
                        else:
                            with open(Registrations, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as RegistrationP:
                                RegistrationP.writelines('Number: {} Time: {} RegLaikas: {}\n'.format(car_numb,Reg_Time, Reg_Tikslus_Laikas))
                                print("* CAR {} Registered for {} hours\n Register ticket time {}".format(car_numb,Reg_Time,Reg_Tikslus_Laikas))
                                break
                elif 'n' in Reg_Time_Verification or 'N' in Reg_Time_Verification:
                    continue

        except ValueError:
            print("Should be a number!")

while True:
    car_numb = input("Input car number:")

    if car_numb_re.match(car_numb) and car_numb.isupper():
        # matches!
        print("Match")
        Registration = True
        TicketReg(car_numb)
        break
    elif car_numb.islower():
        print("Wrong number format. Should be (XXX123)")
        continue
```

** EDIT
For those who don't understand the question this is what I need again:

```
with open(Registrations, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as RegistrationC:
                        if 'Number: %s ' % (car_numb) in RegistrationC.read():
                            print("*Already existing vehicle!")
                            return False
                        else:
                            with open(Registrations, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as RegistrationP:
                                RegistrationP.writelines('Number: {} Time: {} RegLaikas: {}\n'.format(car_numb,Reg_Time, Reg_Tikslus_Laikas))
                                print("* CAR {} Registered for {} hours\n Register ticket time {}".format(car_numb,Reg_Time,Reg_Tikslus_Laikas))
                                return False
```

From this if the numbers are found in the txt file I need to end the bool with break or return false and then return to While True bool.

Comment: Can you specify the desired behavior of the program from the user perspective?  I guess we have an x/y problem at hand because you specify along an already given implementation.  Maybe a complete rework would be feasible.

Comment: Yes, the user should enter the numbers of the car he would like let's say 'Register', and if the system recognizes that those numbers are in txt file the script "Reloads" for user lets say to enter other car numbers.

Comment: what is `car_numb_re`?

Comment: car_numb_re = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$')

Answer (score 0):

If I've read it correctly I think you want to be able to break out of TicketReg at a given point and then break out of the 'if' block which contained the call to TicketReg? If so I think you could solve the issue by having TicketReg return something. So at the point you want to break out of TicketReg you could have

```
return False
```

Then if you call it as

```
carry_on=TicketReg(car_numb)
```

and then in the elif block of the main code you could change to

```
elif car_numb.islower() and carry_on
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood what you want correctly. But if you just want to exist the TicketReg function and go back to your while loop you need to add a return statement.

```
def TicketReg(car_numb):
while True:
    if car_numb == "12":
        print ("here is what i need")
        return True
    else:
        print("Did not found what i need")
        return False

while True:
car_numb = input("Input car number:")
if car_numb == "12":
    TicketReg(car_numb)
    continue
else:
    print("Try again")
    continue
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'need to end the bool with break'?